# React Native - Components of the same type are scrolling together

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, native-base

I am using **NativeBase** with **React Native**.

This is how tabs are created with **NativeBase**:

```
<Tabs>
  <Tab heading="Tab1">
    <Tab1 />
  </Tab>
  <Tab heading="Tab2">
    <Tab2 />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

I am creating those tabs within a loop:

```
[someArray].map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Tab
                    key={index}
                    heading={
                        <TabHeading>
                            <Text>{item.tabText}</Text>
                        </TabHeading>
                    }>
                    <List type={item.listType} data={item.listData}/>
                </Tab>
            );
        });
```

Everything works fine except the fact that when I am vertically scrolling a **List** (custom component) in one tab - it is simultaneously scrolling in all other tabs too. This is a strange effect.

Naturally, I would like every **List** to be a separate entity and to be scrollable on its own.

Tried to add `key={index}` and many other manipulations but cannot make it working.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you add more code or add this to codesandbox or similar?

Comment: There can also be something wrong in the list component. Can you check if you are using different index for the items in the list component across tabs?

Comment: @paruchuri-p the problem is that I am not sure which exact code will help. This List: "<List type={item.listType} data={item.listData}/>" is simultaneously scrolling under each tab. List that are shorter than others simply leave empty space under them.

Comment: @paruchuri-p updated the question with the List component.

Comment: Instead of index as the key to the list, can you a different one - like an identifier or id of the item. That might solve your issue.

Comment: @paruchuri-p tried to add id to the List - same effect.

Comment: Can you add the data for the array and list items.

Comment: Also try adding a key to List and see if it helps.

Comment: @paruchuri-p updated the post with ListItem

Comment: Not the listItem. The data that you are passing.

Comment: @RajenderKumar, if I give it a different component it works as expected. It looks like it wants a separate instance of the same component. How can I give it a separate instance of the same component?

Comment: @paruchuri-p [{
                tabText: "Actions",
                listType: "success",
                listData: [1,2,3]}]

Comment: The key for all the list items in different lists is the same. That is the issue. Try appending the index of the tab to the index of the list item like '1_1,1_2' for first tab and '2_1, 2_2' for the second tab and so on.

Comment: The only way we can look into more is if we can see a working example.

Comment: @paruchuri-p updated with the whole App.js. it is a working version.

Comment: I will give it a try. Can you please provide some sample data you are using...?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
<List type={item.listType} data={item.listData} ind={index}/>
```

And use that in List

```
renderList() {
        return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                const newIndex = index + '_' + this.props.ind
                <ListItem type={this.props.type} text={item} key={newIndex}/>
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: What if you add key to the List
<List type={item.listType} data={item.listData} key={index}/>